# Create an image(Table Entity) which keeps on changing text on it , whenever i change its value/text init

Tags: java, image, swing

[image: Image Example]

i want to create a Database designer so i might also need a way to have UI for making relationship between two tables. Tool : JAVA swing

Comment: JList? JTable? Maybe?

Comment: have you used any Database Designer ?? its like i double click image enter the value eg. table name and that would automatically change the title of the table. Is it possible by using Jlist or JTable ?

Comment: I have tried nothing yet !

Comment: question whole row can be editable, or only columns name without data type, or ???

Comment: Depends. How do you plan to layout the separate entities? Are they suppose to be free floating?

Comment: same as shown in figure column name and data type only ::P.S  sorry for late reply..had electricity breakdown

Comment: @MadProgrammer : yes they can be floating no fixed position

Comment: Study existing [*open source database design tools*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/124467/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is, no.  There are no ready made components.  You're going to have to roll up your selves and get your hands dirty.

Break your problem down.

You need the entity to be floatable.  The only two (decent) choices you have are `JLayeredPane` and `JDesktopPane`.  Which you choice will depend on the features you want to implement.  I'd probably start with `JLayeredPane`.  This will allow you to position components where you want them and also provides the ability to more easily control the Z-level.

The problem with this, is you will become responsible for not only positioning the components, but also resizing them.

Next, you need an entity component.

This would be, to my mind, a series of compound components.  You'd need a "header" or "title" component, which would provide the name of the table, the expand control and a means by which you can drag it.

I'd start with a simple `JPanel`.  Onto which I would add a `JLabel`, a `JTextField` and either a `JButton` or `JLabel` to act as the expand control, depending on what look I was after.

The `JLabel` will act as the title for the header.  The `JTextField` would as as the editor.  Start by making the text field hidden.  With a little bit of clever use of a layout manager, you can place two components in the space place.  When the text field is made visible, it will be able to lay over the label.

You will need to add a mouse listener and mouse motion listener this component.  When clicked, the editor should be shown.  Use an `ActionListener` and `FocusListener` to determine when the user has finished editing and update the label and hide the editor.  You'll probably also want to bind a <kbd>Esc</kbd> to the field to allow the user to cancel the edit, key bindings are best for this.

You will also need to track the mouse drag events so you can reposition the "entity"

This header component would then be added to the entity component.

You would need either a `JList` or `JTable` to hold the field information.  To my mind, a `JTable` would provide the most functionality, allowing you to more easily edit the field information.

You will also need to perform some custom painting to provide links from one table to another.  This is a non-trival problem and is going to need some seriously good design on your part.

Every thing you need to get started can be found at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), but you're also going to need to read through and understand [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Comment: have you ever done this thing before ?? can i have a code Example ??

Comment: Have you ever used Swing before? You stand there and abuse me, then ask for an example?

Comment: im not abusing , i m just asking ! because i need an example to see how that can work .. sorry you took my wordings in a wrong sense :S

Comment: i was just asking you for one coded example .. if you have worked on something like this.. i never meant to offend you. yes im using swing for the 1st time in my project i would be very thankful if you help me out :)

Comment: Appologies for been tetchy, taking care of my 10 month old while my is sick, haven't slept in 6 days. Read through the links and try something, when you have a problem post a question. People will reward effort

Comment: thankyou soo much i will read through the links :) takecare p.s. hope you get well soon :)